# UIScrollView offsetting content double the requested amount

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiscrollview

### The Issue

My PSWSnapshotView's end up exactly snapshotIndex too far to the right inside the _scrollView (40px offset). Yet, they are set with their frame to have the first one at (0, 0), though that first one shows up at (snapshotInset, 0) instead :/.

### The Code

```
- (void)layoutViews
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    CGFloat pageWidth = frame.size.width - (snapshotInset * 2);
    CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, pageWidth, frame.size.height);
    NSInteger pageCount = [applications count];

    [pageControl setNumberOfPages:pageCount];
    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(snapshotInset, 0.0f, pageWidth, frame.size.height)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((pageWidth * pageCount) + 1.0f, frame.size.height)];

    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
        PSWSnapshotView *view;
        if ([snapshotViews count] <= i)
        {
            PSWSnapshotView *view = [[PSWSnapshotView alloc] initWithFrame:pageFrame application:[applications objectAtIndex:i]];
            view.delegate = self;
            [scrollView addSubview:view];
            [snapshotViews addObject:view];
            [view release];
        }
        else
        {
            view = [snapshotViews objectAtIndex:i];
            [view setFrame:pageFrame];
        }

        pageFrame.origin.x += pageWidth;
    }
}
```

### The Values

self.frame.size.width = 320;
self.frame.size.height = 370;
snapshotInset = 40;
[applications count] = 2;

All the sizes and frames are set correctly (I checked w/ NSLog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you possibly setting the scrollView.contentOffset somewhere, independent of this? Also, and this may just be a copy/paste issue, you reference both snapshotInset and _snapshotInset.